# Joomla/PHP/Ajax - ajax validate username in registration form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am trying to do AJAX username verification in joomla registration form in table com_users. I have ajax validate custom fields and this works fine. But when I try anythink (name, username, mail) validate in table com_users, response is NULL (request is ok.)

here is my js with inputmask plugin:

```
        // START #username
        var input_username = document.getElementById("jform_username");
        var inputParent_username = $(input_username).parent();
        $(input_username).inputmask('*{4,40}',{
            greedy:false,
            placeholder:'_',
        allowPlus: false,
        allowMinus: false,
        definitions: {
                '*': {
                    validator: "[0-9A-Za-z@_-]"
                }
            },  
            oncomplete: function () {
                $(inputParent_username).addClass("complete").removeClass("incomplete");
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                timeout:3000,
                    url:"/components/MY_COMPONENT/check_username.php",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: $('#jform_username').serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#jform_username').siblings(".fa").removeClass("fa-exclamation-circle").addClass("fa-cog fa-spin");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        obj=data;
                        console.log(obj);
                        if(obj == 0) {
                            $('#jform_username').siblings("i").removeClass("fa-cog fa-spin fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
                            $('#jform_username').addClass("valid-fail").removeClass("validate").css({"color":"#cf0404"});
                            $(inputParent_username).addClass("valid-fail").removeClass("validate");
                        } else if(obj == 1) {
                            $('#jform_username').siblings("i").removeClass("fa-cog fa-spin fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
                            $('#jform_username').addClass("validate").removeClass("valid-fail").removeAttr("style");
                            $(inputParent_username).addClass("validate").removeClass("valid-fail");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        console.log(err.Message);
                    }
                });
            },
            onincomplete: function () {
                $(inputParent_username).addClass("incomplete");
            }
        });
        // END #username
```

why is this happening? joomla block requests to com_users or just me totally stupid?